# JQuery datepicker with time picker?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

I am looking for a JQuery DatePicker with a time picker which can work with ASP.NET. I found http://milesich.com/timepicker/ which looks nice but I am getting an 'Error: $("#hourSlider").slider is not a function.. error from their timepicker.js

Also found http://code.google.com/p/dyndatetime/ but the time picker is clunky.

Any other recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you including the jquery UI javascript? Your slider error is almost certainly because you don't have the UI loading on your page.
Try adding:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If you don't need the date/time picker to be bundled in the same UI widget then I thought [this](http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/) was quite a nice solution to making a useable time picker.

Regarding the slider error, could you post a bit more example code, as my first and most obvious guess was wrong :)

Comment: it's included. I was using the core Datepicker successfully.

Comment: Sorry to harp on, but can you just confirm that? the Datepicker is a different download to the slider and it's possible to use one without having the other.

Comment: I found the problem. I didn't include his jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js because I had one already. I didn't notice at the time these are custom ones and could be different.